# How to stop a function at a specific time and continue with next function in python?

Tags: python, function, timing

I have a code:

```
function_1()
function_2()
```

Normally, function_1() takes 10 hours to end.
But I want function_1() to run for 2 hours, and after 2 hours, function_1 must return and program must continue with function_2(). It shouldn't wait for function_1() to be completed. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Clarify please, do you want to interrupt first function or launch the second while first one still work?

Comment: There are various ways to accomplish it - [sched module](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html), threads, multiprocessing, generators etc. etc. However, the best solution for your problem depends upon your problem, naturally. What does `function_1()` does? How does it do it? Could you post the code of this function?

Comment: I want function_1 to return after 2 hours.

Comment: function_1 is an optimizer. It tries to minimize a cost, and it may last for more than 10 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes functions in Python able to interrupt their execution and resuming is the use of the "yield" statement -- your function then will work as a generator object. You call the "next" method on this object to have it start or continue after the last yield

```
import time
def function_1():
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
         # do long stuff
         running_time = time.time() -start_time
         if running_time > 2 * 60 * 60: # 2 hours
              yield #<partial results can be yield here, if you want>
              start_time = time.time()



runner = function_1()
while True:
    try:
        runner.next()
    except StopIteration: 
        # function_1 had got to the end
        break
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Then this is not the way to go - check the other answers using multiprocessing or threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind leaving `function_1` running:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

Thread(target=function_1).start()
time.sleep(60*60*2)
Thread(target=function_2).start()
```

Comment: No, it should return after 2 hours. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use module [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org): start function in thread and kill that thread after some time.

Here is example:

```
import gevent

# function which you can't modify
def func1(some_arg)
    # do something
    pass

def func2()
    # do something
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = gevent.Greenlet(func1, 'Some Argument in func1')
    g.start()
    gevent.sleep(60*60*2)
    g.kill()
    # call the rest of functions
    func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
p1 = Process(target=function_1)
p1.start()
p1.join(60*60*2)
if p1.is_alive():p1.terminate()
function_2()
```

I hope this helps

I just tested this using the following code

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def f1():
    print 0
    time.sleep(10000)
    print 1

def f2():
    print 2


p1 = Process(target=f1)
p1.start()
p1.join(6)
if p1.is_alive():p1.terminate()
f2()
```

Output is as expected:

```
0
2
```

Comment: Hi, ı got this error:   File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 118, in join
    assert self._popen is not None, 'can only join a started process'
AssertionError: can only join a started process

Comment: Ya I forgot to start the process. Try again

Comment: function_1 was not run, program started with function_2, what may be wrong?

Comment: `import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_x():
    for _ in xrange(10000):
        print "x"

def print_y():
    for _ in xrange(50):
        print "y"        

p1 = Process(target=print_x)
p1.start()
p1.join(10)
if p1.is_alive():p1.terminate()
print_y()`

Comment: It also puts heavy load on my PC, and I have to restart my computer. ı think it never ends in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can time the execution using the datetime module. Probably your optimizer function has a loop somewhere. Inside the loop you can test how much time has passed since you started the function.

```
def function_1():
    t_end = datetime.time.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)

    while not converged:
        # do your thing
        if datetime.time.now() > t_end:
            return
```